# "UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging :: ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData threw exception: Access is denied."

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

As SP2016 farm administrator, I am trying to work on user profile with PowerShell.
Found several examples that use

```
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
```

But when doing for each on the enumerator, I get the error:

> UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging :: ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData threw exception: Access is denied.

I also added myself to the service with full control and I am SysAdmin on the SQL instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Access denied denote to a permission issue, Meanwhile, you are using a user as a farm admin with sysadmin as server role,So my suggestion is to:

- Make sure that you are running the PowerShell with the farm account (the service account used to configure SharePoint)
- During provisioning UPS, the farm account must be added to local administrator group.

**Note:** After adding the farm account to local administrator group, you must restart the SharePoint 2013 Timer service or restart the server.

- The service account of UPS has a full control permission in the application service settings.

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas.! Running as the service account did the trick. Whish it was more straight forward.

Comment: just Learnt to upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to the central admin web app
2. Click on Manage Service Application
3. Click on the **UserProfileService** Application
4. On the top ribbon, click on the **Administrator** and add yourself with **Full Control**.
5. Also on the Top Ribbon, click on **Permissions**, add yourself, and give **Full control** here as well. If this step is not completed, you will still be receiving Access denied error.

Comment: and no service need to be restarted in this answer :)