# Cannot update user profile custom property through ssom

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, ssom, active-directory-import

I m trying to update the user profile "State" custom property using below code but getting following error.

We have even tried to restart the user profile service but it couldn't fix the issue.

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 public static void UpdateUserProfile(SPSite site, string sAccount, string State)
        {
            try
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
                {
                    using (SPSite _site = new SPSite(site.ID))
                    {
                        var serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                        var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                        if (!profileManager.UserExists(sAccount)) profileManager.CreateUserProfile(sAccount);
                        var userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(sAccount);
                        userProfile["State"].Value = State;
                        userProfile.Commit();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(string.Format("ERROR {0} : {1}.", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.dll but was not
>   handled in user code
>
> Additional information: UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging ::
>   ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData threw exception: Access is
>   denied.

Comment: You can check this URL & see if it configured correctly or not...https://alotofcode.wordpress.com/2015/12/22/change-user-profile-property-in-sharepoint-using-c/

Comment: Hi hardik, i have already checked the field is configuration, as per above URL error is different  as i'm getting.

Comment: Please go through the answer given in here..https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208480/userprofiledbcache-wcflogging-profiledbcacheserviceclient-getuserdata-threw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly check the permission your code running for retrieve User Profile information.

`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` Method is used for running the code block under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool.

In your code snippet, UserProfileManager object is used, so please authorize permission(in `ServiceApplications-->User Profile Service Application`) to this site collection administrator.

Comment: Thanks hardik, authorizing permission resolved the issue.

Comment: If this answer helped you then you can mark it as correct so others will trust this answer easily & get benefit from it. Thanks :)